# How to convert .txt file into xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
Latitude :23.1100348
Longitude:72.5364922
date&time :30:August:2014 05:04:31 PM
gsm cell id: 4993
Neighboring List- Lac : Cid : RSSI
15000     :    7072     :    25 dBm
15000     :    7073     :    23 dBm
15000     :    6102     :    24 dBm
15000     :    6101     :    24 dBm
15000     :    6103     :    17 dBm

Latitude :23.1120549
Longitude:72.5397988
date&time :30:August:2014 05:04:34 PM
gsm cell id: 4993
Neighboring List- Lac : Cid : RSSI
15000     :    7072     :    24 dBm
15000     :    7073     :    22 dBm
15000     :    6102     :    23 dBm
15000     :    6101     :    23 dBm
15000     :    2552     :    16 dBm
```

This is my.txt file I want convert it into xml file like

```
<celldata>
<time>        </time>
<latitude>    </latitude>
<longitude>   </longitude>

</celldata>
```

I tried to make list of all components but I didn't get o/p.I want to store all values of latitude,longitude,gsm cell id,time in list and this will add in xml file something like that.
I write below code.

```
import re

pa = 'Longitude|Latitude|gsm cell id|Neighboring List- Lac : Cid : RSSI'

with open('cell.txt','rw') as file:
    for line in file:
        line.strip()    
        if re.search(pa, line):
            lineInfo = line.split(':')
            title = lineInfo[0]
            value = lineInfo[1]
```

Comment: `time` `latitude` `longitude` is the only values you require in the xml file?? if not please provide the full xml structure

Comment: When you say "I tried to make list of all components but I didn't get o/p." have you tried outputting anything yet? You've just shown the reading code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a .txt file into .xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835956/how-to-parse-a-txt-file-into-xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code as a starter:

```
#!python3

import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Longitude
                       |Latitude
                       |date&time
                       |gsm\s+cell\s+id
                     )
                     \s*:?\s*
                     (?P<value>.*)
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)

root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element

with open('cell.txt') as f:
    celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
    celldata.text = '\n'    # newline before the collected element
    celldata.tail = '\n\n'  # empty line after the celldata element
    for line in f:
        # Empty line starts new celldata element (hack style, uggly)
        if line.isspace():
            celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
            celldata.text = '\n'
            celldata.tail = '\n\n'

        # If the line contains the wanted data, process it.
        m = rex.search(line)
        if m:
            # Fix some problems with the title as it will be used
            # as the tag name.
            title = m.group('title')
            title = title.replace('&', '')
            title = title.replace(' ', '')

            e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title.lower())
            e.text = m.group('value')
            e.tail = '\n'

# Display for debugging            
ET.dump(root)

# Include the root element to the tree and write the tree
# to the file.
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('cell.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

It displays for your example data:

```
<root>
<celldata>
<latitude>23.1100348</latitude>
<longitude>72.5364922</longitude>
<datetime>30:August:2014 05:04:31 PM</datetime>
<gsmcellid>4993</gsmcellid>
</celldata>

<celldata>
<latitude>23.1120549</latitude>
<longitude>72.5397988</longitude>
<datetime>30:August:2014 05:04:34 PM</datetime>
<gsmcellid>4993</gsmcellid>
</celldata>

</root>
```

**Update for the wanted neigbour list:**

```
#!python3

import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Longitude
                       |Latitude
                       |date&time
                       |gsm\s+cell\s+id
                       |Neighboring\s+List-\s+Lac\s+:\s+Cid\s+:\s+RSSI
                     )
                     \s*:?\s*
                     (?P<value>.*)
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)

root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element

with open('cell.txt') as f:
    celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
    celldata.text = '\n'    # newline before the collected element
    celldata.tail = '\n\n'  # empty line after the celldata element
    for line in f:
        # Empty line starts new celldata element (hack style, uggly)
        if line.isspace():
            celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
            celldata.text = '\n'
            celldata.tail = '\n\n'
        else:
            # If the line contains the wanted data, process it.
            m = rex.search(line)
            if m:
                # Fix some problems with the title as it will be used
                # as the tag name.
                title = m.group('title')
                title = title.replace('&', '')
                title = title.replace(' ', '')

                if line.startswith('Neighboring'):
                    neighbours = ET.SubElement(celldata, 'neighbours')
                    neighbours.text = '\n'
                    neighbours.tail = '\n'
                else:
                    e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title.lower())
                    e.text = m.group('value')
                    e.tail = '\n'
            else:
                # This is the neighbour item. Split it by colon,
                # and set the attributes of the item element.
                item = ET.SubElement(neighbours, 'item')
                item.tail = '\n'

                lac, cid, rssi = (a.strip() for a in line.split(':'))
                item.attrib['lac'] = lac
                item.attrib['cid'] = cid
                item.attrib['rssi'] = rssi.split()[0] # dBm removed

# Include the root element to the tree and write the tree
# to the file.
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('cell.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

**Update for accepting empty line before neighbours** -- also better implementation for general purposes:

```
#!python3

import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Longitude
                       |Latitude
                       |date&time
                       |gsm\s+cell\s+id
                       |Neighboring\s+List-\s+Lac\s+:\s+Cid\s+:\s+RSSI
                     )
                     \s*:?\s*
                     (?P<value>.*)
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)

root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element

with open('cell.txt') as f:
    celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
    celldata.text = '\n'    # newline before the collected element
    celldata.tail = '\n\n'  # empty line after the celldata element
    status = 0              # init status of the finite automaton
    for line in f:
        if status == 0:     # lines of the heading expected
            # If the line contains the wanted data, process it.
            m = rex.search(line)
            if m:
                # Fix some problems with the title as it will be used
                # as the tag name.
                title = m.group('title')
                title = title.replace('&', '')
                title = title.replace(' ', '')

                if line.startswith('Neighboring'):
                    neighbours = ET.SubElement(celldata, 'neighbours')
                    neighbours.text = '\n'
                    neighbours.tail = '\n'
                    status = 1  # empty line and then list of neighbours expected
                else:
                    e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title.lower())
                    e.text = m.group('value')
                    e.tail = '\n'
                    # keep the same status

        elif status == 1:   # empty line expected
            if line.isspace():
                status = 2  # list of neighbours must follow
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Empty line expected. (status == {})'.format(status))
                status = 999 # error status

        elif status == 2:   # neighbour or the empty line as final separator

            if line.isspace():
                celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
                celldata.text = '\n'
                celldata.tail = '\n\n'
                status = 0  # go to the initial status
            else:
                # This is the neighbour item. Split it by colon,
                # and set the attributes of the item element.
                item = ET.SubElement(neighbours, 'item')
                item.tail = '\n'

                lac, cid, rssi = (a.strip() for a in line.split(':'))
                item.attrib['lac'] = lac
                item.attrib['cid'] = cid
                item.attrib['rssi'] = rssi.split()[0] # dBm removed
                # keep the same status

        elif status == 999: # error status -- break the loop
            break

        else:
            raise LogicError('Unexpected status {}.'.format(status))
            break

# Display for debugging
ET.dump(root)

# Include the root element to the tree and write the tree
# to the file.
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('cell.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

The code implements so called *finite automaton* where the `status` variable represents its current status. You can visualize it using pencil and paper -- draw small circles with the status numbers inside (called nodes in the graph theory). Being at the status, you allow only some kind of input (`line`). When the input is recognized, you draw the arrow (oriented edge in the graph theory) to another status (possibly to the same status, as a loop returning back to the same node). The arrow is annotated `condition | action'.

The result may look complex at the beginning; however, it is easy in the sense that you can always focus ony on the part of the code that belongs to certain status. And also, the code can be easily modified. However, finite automatons have limited power. But they are just perfect for this kind of problems.

Comment: I also want neighbouring list in this xml file like <Neighbours> cid=' , , ,'  rssi = ' , , ,'                      </Neighbors>

Comment: @yogeshbhimani: *"I want to learn this type of programming please give me some link or anything."* The advice here is both easy and difficult. It depends on your age, on your previous education, on where you want to go, on how much effort you want spend.

Comment: I should warn you that I do not consider my code nice. It is rather hastily put together and need some cleaning (refactoring).

 In my opinion, Stack Overflow is perfect for answering exact questions; however, it is not suitable for mentoring, for discussion of a problem evolved in time. For that case, I suggest another forum. I am personally active at Experts Exchange (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Python/) using the same nick. Let's move the discussion there.

Comment: Suppose After "Neighboring List- Lac : Cid : RSSI" line there is blank line(means there is no value) so I am getting an error so what should i do?

Comment: @yogeshbhimani: updated -- see at the end of the answer. Not everything was checked in the code. But now it can be easily added.