# How to parse a .txt file into .xml?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, elementtree

This is my txt file:

```
In File Name:   C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\File 1.m1
Out File Name:  C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\Output\File 1.m2
In File Size:   Low:    22636   High:   0
Total Process time: 1.859000
Out File Size:  Low:    77619   High:   0

In File Name:   C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\File 2.m1
Out File Name:  C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\Output\File 2.m2
In File Size:   Low:    20673   High:   0
Total Process time: 3.094000
Out File Size:  Low:    94485   High:   0

In File Name:   C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\File 3.m1
Out File Name:  C:\Users\naqushab\desktop\files\Output\File 3.m2
In File Size:   Low:    66859   High:   0
Total Process time: 3.516000
Out File Size:  Low:    217268  High:   0
```

I am trying to parse this to an XML format like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
    <filedata>
        <InFileName>File 1.m1</InFileName>
        <OutFileName>File 1.m2</OutFileName>
        <InFileSize>22636</InFileSize>
        <OutFileSize>77619</OutFileSize>
        <ProcessTime>1.859000</ProcessTime>
    </filedata>
    <filedata>
        <InFileName>File 2.m1</InFileName>
        <OutFileName>File 2.m2</OutFileName>
        <InFileSize>20673</InFileSize>
        <OutFileSize>94485</OutFileSize>
        <ProcessTime>3.094000</ProcessTime>
    </filedata>
    <filedata>
        <InFileName>File 3.m1</InFileName>
        <OutFileName>File 3.m2</OutFileName>
        <InFileSize>66859</InFileSize>
        <OutFileSize>217268</OutFileSize>
        <ProcessTime>3.516000</ProcessTime>
    </filedata>
</root>
```

Here is the code (I am using Python 2) in which I am trying to achieve that:

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>In File Name:
                       |Out File Name:
                       |In File Size:   Low:
                       |Total Process time:
                       |Out File Size:  Low:
                     )
                     (?P<value>.*)
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)

root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element

with open('Performance.txt') as f:
    celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')
    celldata.text = '\n'    # newline before the collected element
    celldata.tail = '\n\n'  # empty line after the celldata element
    for line in f:
        # Empty line starts new celldata element (hack style, uggly)
        if line.isspace():
            celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')
            celldata.text = '\n'
            celldata.tail = '\n\n'

        # If the line contains the wanted data, process it.
        m = rex.search(line)
        if m:
            # Fix some problems with the title as it will be used
            # as the tag name.
            title = m.group('title')
            title = title.replace('&', '')
            title = title.replace(' ', '')

            e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title.lower())
            e.text = m.group('value')
            e.tail = '\n'

# Display for debugging
ET.dump(root)

# Include the root element to the tree and write the tree
# to the file.
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('Performance.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

But I am getting empty values, is it possible to parse this txt to XML?

Comment: where are you getting empty value? can you please be more clear!

Comment: When a full program *does not give expected results*, just split it in smaller parts and try them separately. Here you should begin with simply parsing the input and print the parts you could find. And only them try to build a XML file.

Comment: and also, your regex and subelements name don't match! Are they intentional ?

Comment: I tried the program, I am getting the XML structure and that too just the filedata tag. I took help of an answer to a SO question and changed the Regex according to my structure..

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Sorry, I was editing the text file before uploading it to SO. I'll update the Regex which I used. Still, i think its not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correction with your regex: It should be

```
m = re.search('(?P<title>(In File Name)|(Out File Name)|(In File Size: *Low)|(Total Process time)|(Out File Size: *Low)):(?P<value>.*)',line)
```

and not as what you've given. Because in your regex, `In File Name|Out File Name` means, it will check for `In File Nam` followed but `e` or `O` followed by `ut File Name` and so on.

Suggestion,

You can do it without using regex.
**xml.dom.minidom**  can be used for prettifying your xml string.

I've added the comments inline for better understanding!

> **Node.toprettyxml([indent=""[, newl=""[, encoding=""]]])**
>
> Return a pretty-printed version of the document. indent specifies the indentation string and defaults to a tabulator; newl specifies the string emitted at the end of each line and defaults to

**Edit**

> ```
> import itertools as it
> [line[0] for line in it.groupby(lines)]
> ```
>
> you can use groupby of itertools package to  group consucutive dedup in list lines

So,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

#add first subelement
celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')

import itertools as it
#for every line in input file
#group consecutive dedup to one 
for line in it.groupby(lines):
    line=line[0]
    #if its a break of subelements  - that is an empty space
    if not line:
        #add the next subelement and get it as celldata
        celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'filedata')
    else:
        #otherwise, split with : to get the tag name
        tag = line.split(":")
        #format tag name
        el=ET.SubElement(celldata,tag[0].replace(" ",""))
        tag=' '.join(tag[1:]).strip()
        
        #get file name from file path
        if 'File Name' in line:
            tag = line.split("\\")[-1].strip()
        elif 'File Size' in line:
            splist =  filter(None,line.split(" "))
            tag = splist[splist.index('Low:')+1]
            #splist[splist.index('High:')+1]
        el.text = tag

#prettify xml
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
formatedXML = minidom.parseString(
                          ET.tostring(
                                      root)).toprettyxml(indent=" ",encoding='utf-8').strip()
# Display for debugging
print formatedXML

#write the formatedXML to file.
with open("Performance.xml","w+") as f:
    f.write(formatedXML)
```

Output:
**Performance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <filedata>
  <InFileName>File 1.m1</InFileName>
  <OutFileName>File 1.m2</OutFileName>
  <InFileSize>22636</InFileSize>
  <TotalProcesstime>1.859000</TotalProcesstime>
  <OutFileSize>77619</OutFileSize>
 </filedata>
 <filedata>
  <InFileName>File 2.m1</InFileName>
  <OutFileName>File 2.m2</OutFileName>
  <InFileSize>20673</InFileSize>
  <TotalProcesstime>3.094000</TotalProcesstime>
  <OutFileSize>94485</OutFileSize>
 </filedata>
 <filedata>
  <InFileName>File 3.m1</InFileName>
  <OutFileName>File 3.m2</OutFileName>
  <InFileSize>66859</InFileSize>
  <TotalProcesstime>3.516000</TotalProcesstime>
  <OutFileSize>217268</OutFileSize>
 </filedata>
</root>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! Just one thing, how do I check for more than one new lines, as the txt generated can have some empty lines at the start and end?

Comment: groupby of itertools should do the trick! I've added the edits for the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (*emphasis is mine*):

> re.VERBOSE
>   This flag allows you to write regular expressions that
>   look nicer. **Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a
>   character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash**, and, when a
>   line contains a '#' neither in a character class or preceded by an
>   unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such '#' through
>   the end of the line are ignored.

escape spaces in the regex or use `\s` class